# how can I solve my compiling problem with makefile

Tags: c, makefile

I am trying to compile a simple C function to handle two stacks of ints and sorting them with specific rules.
I had no problem compiling earlier but I can't anymore. and receive this error message :

```
 make: *** No rule to make target `objs/main.c', needed by `push_swap'.  Stop.
```

Below is my code;

```
NAME = push_swap

SRC_DIR = srcs

SRC =   main.c \
        instructions/swap.c \
        instructions/rotate.c \
        instructions/push.c \
        instructions/reverse.c \
        utils/check_duplicate.c \
        utils/chunk_clear.c \
        utils/chunk.c \
        utils/ft_error.c \
        utils/ft_split.c \
        utils/highest.c \
        utils/init_stack.c \
        utils/is_sorted.c \
        utils/lowest.c \
        utils/num.c \
        utils/tab.c \
        sort/five.c \
        sort/small.c \
        sort/sorter.c \

OBJ_DIR = objs

OBJ = $(addprefix $(OBJ_DIR)/, $(SRC:.c =.o))

HEADER_FOLDER = inc

CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -Werror -Wextra -Wall -I$(HEADER_FOLDER) -g
RM = rm -rf

all:    $(NAME)

$(OBJ_DIR):
    @mkdir -p $(OBJ_DIR)
    @mkdir -p $(OBJ_DIR)/operations
    @mkdir -p $(OBJ_DIR)/sorters
    @mkdir -p $(OBJ_DIR)/utils

$(NAME): $(OBJ_DIR) $(OBJ)
    @cd libft && make && cd ../
    @echo "making push_swap ... \033[32mok\033[0m"
    @$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $(NAME) $(OBJ) $(HEADER)

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.c
    @echo "Compiling ... $@ \033[32mok\033[0m"
    @$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

clean:
    @cd libft && make clean && cd ../
    @echo "Removing object files ... \033[32mok\033[0m"
    @$(RM) $(OBJ) $(OBJ_DIR)

fclean:
    @cd libft && make fclean && cd ../
    @echo "Removing files and program ... \033[32mok\033[0m"
    @$(RM) $(NAME) $(OBJ) $(OBJ_DIR)

re: fclean all

.PHONY: all re fclean clean
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `$(SRC:.c =.o)` doesn't work because of that space (there are no `SRC` names ending with `".c "` (including the last space).

It should be `$(SRC:.c=.o)`.